# Sending events on AWS Eventbridge using Rust

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, aws-event-bridge

I am rewriting some of my python code in rust. I want to build a Hello World program that takes a json event, sends it to a specified bus, and gives me a "success".

this is the equivalent code in python:

```
 response = events_client.put_events(
        Entries=[{
            "Source": SRC_ARN,
            "DetailType": 'event',
            "Detail": json.dumps(payload),
            "EventBusName": DEST_ARN
        }]
    )
```

I started going through the [aws sdk docs](https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-eventbridge/latest/aws_sdk_eventbridge/client/struct.Client.html), then i checked out youtube where i learnt about Rust lambdas (although it is still not helping with my current problem), then the official github repo with SDK usage examples but found no eventbridge examples. I just cant figure how to send events. Here is my code, thanks in advance:

```
use aws_sdk_eventbridge as eeb;
use aws_sdk_eventbridge::types::PutEventsRequestEntry;
use json;

async fn main() -> Result<(), eeb::Error> {
    //configuring the client
    let config = aws_config::load_from_env().await;
    let client = aws_sdk_eventbridge::Client::new(&config);
    let eventjson = json::parse(r#"{"event":"test"}"#);

    //building the event
    let eeb_bus_name = "arn" //replaced my arn for privacy;
    let entry = PutEventsRequestEntry::builder()
        .source("test")
        .detail_type("test_event")
        .event_bus_name(eeb_bus_name).build();

    let resp = client.put_events().entries(entry).endpoint_id(eeb_bus_name);
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is missing `.send().await` where the actual request is being made. Also, `endpoint_id` is the URL subdomain of the endpoint (e.g if the URL for endpoint is `https://abcde.veo.endpoints.event.amazonaws.com`, then the EndpointId is `abcde.veo`), not event bus name.

This code works for me.

```
use aws_sdk_eventbridge as eeb;
use aws_sdk_eventbridge::types::PutEventsRequestEntry;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), eeb::Error> {
    //configuring the client
    let config = aws_config::load_from_env().await;
    let client = aws_sdk_eventbridge::Client::new(&config);
    let event_detail = r#"{"hello": "world"}"#; 

    //building the event
    let eeb_bus_name = "arn";//replaced my arn for privacy;
    let entry = PutEventsRequestEntry::builder()
        .source("test")
        .detail(event_detail)
        .detail_type("json")
        .event_bus_name(eeb_bus_name)
        .build();

    let _resp = client.put_events().entries(entry).endpoint_id(input).send().await?;
    println!("EB event sent sucesssfully");
    Ok(())
}
```